# Receiveing using Datagram socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, datagram

Since UDP is connectionless, is it possible for a single UDP socket/port on a client to receive packets from different servers(connections)? Or would it need separate connections to receive from each server?

I am designing a client which receives packets from 5 servers using UDP. Does this require me to create 5 sockets each on different ports on my client? Or can i receive data using a single port/socket at my client?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can send and receive datagrams from multiple clients at the same time. for this you'd use [`sendto()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html) and [`recvfrom()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html).